org.bson.json.JsonParseException: Failed to parse string as a date
I'm trying to parse this and got the error org.bson.json.JsonParseException: Failed to parse string as a date: 2024-05-01T00:00:00.000-0400
static Collection<Document> parsePipeline(String pipeline, Map<String, Object> placeholders = null) {
    String pipelineWrap = '{ "pipeline": ' + populatePlaceholders(pipeline, placeholders) + ' }'
    Document aggregation = Document.parse(pipelineWrap)
    return aggregation.pipeline
}

Actually, the placeholders contains a date. It was of type LocaDateTime, then I convert it to Mongo format before parsing:
{
   def date = ZonedDateTime.of((LocalDateTime) v, ZoneId.systemDefault())
   text = text.replaceAll(Pattern.quote(part1.toString()), "ISODate('" + date.format(MONGO_ISO_DATE_FORMAT) + "')")
}

I tried to print out the date.format(MONGO_ISO_DATE_FORMAT) and I got 2024-05-01T00:00:00.000-0400
From my understanding, there's something wrong about this date so it gave me the error.
How can I fix my issue?
Thank you so much in advance!
I tried to change the format of the date, parsing it before format to Mongo but it didn't solve the issue.
